# Discord.py - How can I save data in .json for a specific server?

Tags: python, discord.py

I need to save a data for a specific server only. How can I do it?

For example to save coins:

```py
def set_coins(member: discord.Member, amount: int):
  with open('data/bank.json', 'r') as f:
    balance = json.load(f)

    balance[str(member.id)] = amount

  with open('data/bank.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(balance, f, indent=4)
```

As you can see, it saves only member id (for all the servers where it is).

Comment: "As you can see" no we can't, please include your input and output json files

Comment: "I need to save a data for a specific server only." Well, did you consider writing code to check whether the `member` is from that server?

Answer (score 1):

json file can contain another json file.

`balance[str(guild.id)][str(member.id)]` is what you want.